# Android How to get the number of times an application has been executed/opened for all installed apps

Tags: android

I was trying to see how many times an app has been opened/used so far.

Using this I can get a list of ResolveInfos, which contain all packageManagerInfo I
might need. But I don't know if there is any field or method that would return me the number of times that this application has been executed/opened.

Or maybe there's a much simpler way I just don't know.

```
public List<ResolveInfo> getInstalledApps(Context context) {
    final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
    mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    return context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);
}
```

Many thanks in advance,
Sakura

Answer (score 2):

Use a shared preference (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) as a counter.

Comment: Unfortunately I'd like to know that value for all already installed applications, not a specifically mine application.

Comment: Ouch! It may be possible by developing a ActivityManager monitoring Service. The drawback is that you will monitor only when that service is up and running… I have no more idea.

Comment: Edit your question to ask what you actually want to know: "I'd like to know that value for all already installed applications".